# How do I send Alt+Ctrl+F1 through Synergy?

Tags: shortcut-keys, synergy

I use Synergy to control both of my desktops from the same keyboard and mouse.  Is there a way to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or related combinations) to the client desktop using Synergy?

I tried using the suggestion below, but got:

```
$ chvt 1
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Other ideas?  I would still prefer a way to send the actual keystrokes over synergy, but if that's not possible, a work around that works will be accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run:

```
sudo chvt 1
```

Changing virtual tty's requires administrative privileges.

Comment: Ah.  This did switch terminals.  HOWEVER, synergy stops working.  With a little digging, this is because synergy requires X, so it *can't* work in a non-X environment, like one of the other virtual TTY's...   Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Synergy, but...

I guess with <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+F1</kbd> you intend to switch from the X-Screen to the console.
First guess for synergy: that will not work.
But to answer that particular:
you can open up a terminal on the computer you want to invoke <kbd>Alt+Ctrl+F1</kbd> and enter

```
chvt 1
```

to change to virtual terminal number 1.

Comment: sorry, not sure if this really IS an answer to your question, I should have commented on your question instead...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to switch to console number 1.  However, this didn't work.  See my edit...